# ImageView + scaleAspectFit in containerView, then in cell

Tags: swift, uikit, rounded-corners, snapkit

i have a cell, that contains containerView with top and bottom cornerRadius = 8.
Then i have to put UIImageView with contentMode = .scaleAspectFit and corner radius ONLY on the top (cornerRadius = 8)
But the problem that code 'corner radius' is not working with contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

Here is properties

```
 let containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        return view
    }()

let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        imageView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        return imageView
    }()
```

Here is SnapKit method

```
private func setupViews() {
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        containerView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(containerView.snp.top)
            make.trailing.equalTo(containerView.snp.trailing)
            make.leading.equalTo(containerView.snp.leading)
        }
}
```

as a result i got [image: wrong result] , i need my image.top EqualToContainer.top and with cornerRadius on the top

Comment: just give a background color to image view to check frame. I think its your image issue the height of image maybe small and you are using fit mode

Comment: sure, but i need to cut the void from top and make a cornerRadius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given the image view a height constraint, and a `UIImageView` has no intrinsic size until its `.image` has been set.

So, when you set the image, the image view will use the height of the **image** to set its own height. Then, because you're telling it to use `.scaleAspectFit`, you get the image centered in the new height.

What you need to do is leave the image view at the default of `.scaleToFill` and then set its height constraint to use the same proportion as the image.

A quick example, using these two images:

[image] [image]

We want it to look like this (I've exaggerated the corner radius to make it obvious):

[image] [image]

We'll use a `UIView` subclass -- but the same thing will apply when using this in a cell:

```
class AspectView: UIView {

    public var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            // set the image view's image
            imageView.image = image
            // if height constraint is already set
            if let h = hConstraint {
                // deactivate it
                h.isActive = false
            }
            // set new height constraint to image aspect ratio
            imageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                self.hConstraint = make.height.equalTo(imageView.snp.width).multipliedBy(image!.size.height / image!.size.width).constraint
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var hConstraint: Constraint!

    private let containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        // using corner radius of 32 to make it very obvious
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 32
        // this will clip the image view subview
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        return view
    }()
    
    private let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        return imageView
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupViews()
    }
    
    public func addImage(_ img: UIImage) {
        imageView.image = img
        print(img.size)
        if let h = hConstraint {
            h.isActive = false
        }
        imageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            self.hConstraint = make.height.equalTo(imageView.snp.width).multipliedBy(img.size.height / img.size.width).constraint
        }
    }
    private func setupViews() {
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        containerView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(containerView.snp.top)
            make.trailing.equalTo(containerView.snp.trailing)
            make.leading.equalTo(containerView.snp.leading)
        }
        
        // so we can see the containerView frame
        containerView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
    }
    
}
```

and a sample controller class - tapping anywhere will toggle between the two images:

```
class AspectTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    let testView = AspectView()
    
    let imgNames: [String] = [
        "p320x160",
        "p320x240",
    ]
    var imgIdx: Int = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // bkg640x360
    
        view.addSubview(testView)
        
        testView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(40.0)
            make.height.equalTo(400.0)
        }

        if let img = UIImage(named: imgNames[imgIdx % imgNames.count]) {
            testView.image = img
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        imgIdx += 1
        if let img = UIImage(named: imgNames[imgIdx % imgNames.count]) {
            testView.image = img
        }
    }
}
```